# Get a connection of local db (.mdf file) in Visual Studio 12

Tags: database-connection

I have made a connection to a local db in my project. Here's my code:

```
class Connection
{
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string mycon = @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" + @"attachdbfilename=G:\distributor_Portal\distributor_Portal\App_Data\DistributorPortal.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
        return con;
    }

    public static String GetConnectionString()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

My problem is that I do not want to give the complete address, like `G:\distributor_Portal\distributor_Portal\App_Data\DistributorPortal.mdf`. I want to give a reference path.

Comment: i have also tried this
..\..\App_Data\DistributorPortal.mdf
but this is not working.. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

change the attach file part to:

```
@"attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DistributorPortal.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```